# Laravel Downloadable File Not Getting Download

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have connected my laravel project with my network folder and connected it to a local folder,

code to upload it to the network folder

```
 $destinationPath = Storage::disk('shared')->url('uploads/files/') . $name;
```

so its a console command while running pdf files being uploaded to my network drive

I need is to download such uploaded files through my view

example file location would be like this

```
file://laptop-lo2am2jp/storage/uploads/files/aa.pdf
```

so while uploading I am inserting it to a database column, so I am passing the URL to view

view code

```
 <div class="col-md-3">
                     <a href="{{$example->url}}">
                     <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">View pdf</button>                                             
                     </a>
                  </div>
```

when I click it loads with my localhost URL and saying no such files

```
http://localhost:8000/laptop-lo2am2jp/storage/uploads/files/aa.pdf
```

can someone help with these,

I am not sure am I explained it properly

Thank you

Comment: Did you link your `storage` folder to the `public` folder? `php artisan storage:link`?

Answer (score 0):

At first, write your path to database

```
public function update(Request $request)
{
    $path = $request->file('avatar')->store('avatars');

    return $path;
}
```

Then you have this path to download.
Or you can use PHP substr() to return a part of your string.